# Angular8 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, undefined

Ive already searched a solution but none of them works.

After clicking on a button edit it redirects me to edit-event and I'm getting :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService
    .getEventById(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
    .subscribe((ev) => this.event = ev);
```

After the subscribe if I do this : console.log(this.event) it returns me undefined.
Wherease `.subscribe(console.log(ev));`  returns me an object.
Don't know why `this.event = ev`  doesn't work Ive already used this in another component and the mapping works.

The service :

```
getEventById(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get<EventsDto>(this.urlevent + '?id=' + id);
  }
```

In edit-event.component.html, {{event.name}} is printed how is this possible
if this.event is undefined as we've seen before with : `.subscribe((ev) => this.event = ev)`

Comment: Add breakpoint inside subscribe then recreate issue with Network tab open. You should see outbound packed sent inside subscribe. This should tell you the result is what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - Group your asynchronous logic by calling `this.http.get()` inside of the button press function and apply any downstream logic within its `subscribe()` method

---

As you are dealing with asynchronous code, you have to take extra care to ensure that the asynchronous functions (e.g. your `this.httpClient.get` request) have returned the data before you try and interact with it, display it etc.

As you quite rightly mentioned, your `.subscribe(console.log(ev))` is correctly logging data but your synchronous `console.log(ev)` is not. This is due to the fact that the sychronous `console.log(ev)` will be executed immediately after your `this.httpClient.get()` has been called. As it takes some time for the asynchronous data to be returned, the variable `ev` is still `undefined` at the point in time that the sychronous `console.log(ev)` is fired. Calling `console.log(ev)` from within your `subscribe()` block instead waits specifically for the data to be returned from the `this.httpClient.get()` before executing, guaranteeing that `ev` will have the data you requested (or an error).

With that in mind, a simple way to mitigate your issue would be to call the `this.http.get()` request inside the button click event and include any downstream functionality within the `.subscribe()` function. This will allow the compiler to guarantee that some data is available at the time that the subsequent functions are called.

**.html**

```
<button (click)="buttonClick()></button>
```

**.ts**

```
buttonClick() {
  this.eventService
    .getEventById(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
    .subscribe(ev => {
      this.event = ev
      // your code here, e.g. createEventsDto(ev)
    });
```